# How to handle invalid delete votes (on an answer) when OP answers his own question

Tags: discussion

Once in a while I run across a situation like this one:

[Uploading CSV with multiple columns into SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208624/uploading-csv-with-multiple-columns-into-sql)

Where the OP asked a question, then ended up posting an answer that explained the cause of his problem... but does so in a way that can be someone confusing for a reviewer.

Usually I leave a note saying that this is indeed an answer to the question, as I did here.

Is there a better way to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That post was an answer to the question and a comment on another answer all smushed together.

Separate the two.

The text that was simply commenting on another answer should simply be removed, leaving just the answer to the question.  I have made such an edit.  You can also comment on the post indicating that if he would like to respond to an answer, he should do so in a comment, and that he should ensure that his answer is just an answer.

After the edit, the post is clearly an answer, not a comment on another answer, and you don't need to worry (hopefully) about other reviewers deleting it.